# handle Status Code:200 OK on ajax save form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, haml

I have the following HAML form:

```
.row
    .col-lg-6   
      .panel.panel-default
        .panel-heading
          %h1.box-title
            %i.fa.fa-calendar.fa-fw
            Availability
        .panel-body
          = form_tag dashboard_kid_availabilities_url(current_kid), :method => 'post', id: "save-availability", remote: true do
            .form-group
              = _("Date")
              = select_date(Time.now + 1.day, order: [:day, :month, :year])
              %br
              = _("Hour")
              = select_hour(Time.now )
            .form-group
              = submit_tag _('Save'),  class: 'btn btn-blabloo btn-xs'
```

With the following ajax request:

```
:javascript
  $("#save-availability").submit(function () {
    var availability_day = $("#date_day").val();
    var availability_month = $("#date_month").val();
    var availability_year = $("#date_year").val();
    var availability_hour = $("#date_hour").val();
    var calendar = $("#calendar").fullCalendar();
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      type: "POST",
      data: {"date_day" : availability_day, "date_month" : availability_month, "date_year" : availability_year, "date_hour" : availability_hour},
      success: function(result){
        alert("salvada disponibilidad");
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("Impossible to connect");
        console.log(xhr.statusText);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

And this is the code of my controller:

```
def create
  @availability = Availability.new()
  @availability.availability_date     = (params[:date][:day] + "/" + params[:date][:month] + "/" + params[:date][:year] + " "+ params[:date][:hour]).to_str
  @availability.end_availability_date = (params[:date][:day] + "/" + params[:date][:month] + "/" + params[:date][:year] + " "+ (params[:date][:hour].to_i + 1).to_s).to_str
  @availability.kid = current_kid
  if @availability.save
    flash[:notice] = 'Availability created successfully'
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {  render json: @availability.to_json, success: :ok, error: false  }
    end
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Availability not created'
  end
end
```

Everything work great (the record is saved), but the success code on my javascript code it's never execute, instead the error code it's executed.

I'm getting this error on my console:

> POST http:// localhost:3000/dashboard/kids/jean_oso/availabilities 500
>   (Internal Server Error) application.js?body=1:8707send
>   application.js?body=1:8707jQuery.extend.ajax
>   application.js?body=1:8137(anonymous function)
>   edit:1808jQuery.event.dispatch
>   application.js?body=1:5096elemData.handle application.js?body=1:4767
>   Impossible to connect edit:1816 Internal Server Error edit:1817 error
>   edit:1818 Internal Server Error

What I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check your console for request type because you are not passing any dataType option in ajax call. It might be look like `MyController#create */*` if you didn't pass any dataType and not rendering json response properly.

Comment: @NitinVerma But I'm passing the params using the data variable on my ajax. What do you suggest??? Thanks

Comment: If your console not showing request type. Then you can specify dataType in your ajax request like `dataType:"json"`. Because your other code not having any problem

Comment: I did it but I still get into the error section

Comment: try this in your response `format.json {  render json: @availability, success: 200}`